# Dapper... Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: dapper

I'm starting with Dapper in a C# application (I currently use Entity in most places) and i'm having an issue with a simple query.

I keep getting back "Must declare scalar variable '@ReportId'" but I am declaring it!

```
db.Execute(@"INSERT INTO cdr_Requests (ReportId, ReportName, StartTime, EndTime, Status, ReportUrl, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, Timezone, CdrReportRead) VALUES (@ReportId, @ReportName, @StartTime, @EndTime, @Status, @ReportUrl, @CreatedAt, @UpdatedAt, @Timezone, @CdrReportRead)", new { data.id, data.report_name, data.start_time, data.end_time, data.status, data.report_url, data.created_at, data.updated_at, data.timezone, data.cdrreportread });
```

Here is my class:

```
    public class cdr_Request
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string ReportId { get; set; }

        public string ReportName { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm just having trouble figuring out what is going on!

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Are you sure the posted code is producing the exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok apparently I had a complete brain fart and was looking at the wrong line. I changed to this and it works:

```
db.Execute(@"INSERT INTO cdr_Requests (ReportId, ReportName, StartTime, EndTime, Status, ReportUrl, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, Timezone, CdrReportRead) 
    VALUES (@ReportId, @ReportName, @StartTime, @EndTime, @Status, @ReportUrl, @CreatedAt, @UpdatedAt, @Timezone, @CdrReportRead)", new {
     ReportId = data.id,
     ReportName = data.report_name,
     StartTime = data.start_time,
     EndTime = data.end_time,
     Status = data.status,
     ReportUrl = data.report_url,
     CreatedAt = data.created_at,
     UpdatedAt = data.updated_at,
     Timezone = data.timezone,
     CdrReportRead = 0
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any of ma F# peeps come across the 'must declare the scalar variable issue' - often the cause is that you declared your parameters record in a private module. E.g.

```
module private MyStuff =
    type Params = { MyParam : int }
```

You'll just have to move the type or de-private the module.